# Anyway for azerothcore to go the background or system tray?

Tags: azerothcore

I want to know if you can put `authserver` and `worldserver` to the background. I know mangos do this and since in the end, Azerothcore is based on mangos so I'm wondering if Azerothcore can still do this.

Answer (score 3):

Or another way I do it for windows is use [RBtray](https://github.com/benbuck/rbtray)

```
RBTray is a small Windows program that runs in the background and allows almost any window to be minimized to the system tray by:
Right-Clicking its minimize button
Shift-Right-Clicking on its title bar
Using the Windows-Alt-Down hotkey
Note that not all all of these methods will work for every window, so please use whichever one works for your needs.
```

Just a guess that your trying to move console windows to system tray?.

Comment: I would prefer it to go to the background or tray automatically